# Get multiple scope_identity while inserting data with table-valued parameter

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, table-valued-parameters, scope-identity

I am inserting multiple rows into Table1 using table-valued parameter.
Now I want to insert Table1's scope identity to Table2 with some values.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: use `output clause` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Output Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause for that, lets look at a sample

suppose your `Table1` looks like this

```
Table1(Table1_ID int identity, Name varchar(100), Email varchar(100), ...)
```

Now lets insert and catch all new ID's and Names :

```
declare @OutputTbl table (ID INT, Name varchar(100))

insert into Table1(Name, Email)
output inserted.Table1_ID, inserted.Name into @OutputTbl(ID, Name)
VALUES ('john doe', 'john@somewhere.com'), 
       ('Anna', 'Anna@1com')

select * from @OutputTbl
```

the result in @OutputTbl will be

```
ID  Name    
--  --------    
18  john doe    
19  Anna
```

Now you can off course insert all rows from `@OutputTbl` into another table if you so desire

```
insert into Table2 (Table1_ID, Name) 
select ID, Name
from   @OutputTbl
```